# Conda env activation: Weird "must be sourced" error

Tags: bash, zsh, conda

I am trying to run the following:

```
source activate env-name
```

But I am receiving an error that tells me that the call to `activate` must be sourced. In the Conda `activate` script, there's an if block near the beginning that tests `"$(basename "$0")"`, specifically whether it's equal to `activate`, in which case it will raise the exception I'm referring to. A little bit of fiddling with the script (i.e., `echo $0; return 1`) and I found out that it does indeed think that the 0th argument that I am passing in is `activate` rather than `source`. This is perplexing because I know that my command includes `source` in it and that that should be the 0th argument. I'm not sure what else there is to do. Does anybody have any clues?

In case it's important, I am using zsh as my default shell and it seems that the `activate` script is a bash script, but I don't think that should matter (it doesn't elsewhere for me, only in this specific environment on my work laptop). I am able to get around this whole thing by just commenting out the whole check (and a couple of other minor changes), but I'd rather not have to do that in this particular case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been having the same issue, the only workaround I've found is:

```
source <PATH TO ANACONDA>/anaconda3/bin/activate <ENV NAME>
```

EDIT: adding the line:

```
export PATH=$PATH:<PATH TO ANACONDA>/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
```

to your bashrc (or zsh etc) will add source to your path and you will be able to use `source` as normal.

Comment: I think this is the way to go. I don't understand what was causing the problem, but this seems straightforward enough.

Answer (score 0):

** I DON'T HAVE ENOUGH REPUTATION, SO I REPLY THIS. (I wanna just comment but I can't)

It can be solve that you know this.
"Run 'Source activate envname'" means you have to run this command on correct path or directory.

If you install anaconda3 on /home/user/anaconda3/
your correnct source path is /home/user/anaconda3/bin/

```
/home/user/anaconda3/bin/ activate tensorflow
```

or

```
cd /home/user/anaconda3/bin
. activate tensorflow
```

So, I already solve this problem through adding path(or move correct path)

Answer (score 0):

I got similar error because I was using [asdf-vm](https://asdf-vm.com/#/) which masks actual binaries with shims. As documented [here](https://asdf-vm.com/#/core-manage-versions?id=shims), scripts that need to be sourced must be accessed directly because *asdf* uses `exec` system call. So in my case, the following command worked:

```sh
source $(asdf which activate) <ENV NAME>
```

While this answer is specific to *asdf*, the error you're getting suggests you were in a similar situation where the call to `activate` was intercepted by some other executable.